# How can you retrieve a pages source code (after javascript has ran) using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

On my page, javascript adds a lot of classes on page load (depending on the page).
How can I wait til javascript has added those classes, then get the HTML using either Javascript or PHP from a different file?

Comment: Firefox's Web Dev toolbar should be able to do this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301554/is-page-source-before-or-after-javascript-has-been-rendered

Answer (score 3):

When the page has finished loading, POST the rendered source back to a PHP script using Ajax.

```
$(function()
{
    var data = $('body').html();
    $.post('/path/to/php/script', data);
});
```

(This example assumes you're using jQuery)

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for. I'll create temp' PHP files and send the users to those.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). If you are using Google Chrome, you could also use the [Google Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/).

These tools will allow you to view the live DOM of the page as well as track any changes made by your javascript. Tools like these are essential to us as developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not receive the rendered HTML source by an other resource other than from JavaScript on your page itself. After JS finished all the content changes in the HTML, you could post the HTML source to a PHP on the server and save it.

Pseudo code:

```
// JavaScript using jQuery
setTimeout("jQuery.post('/catch.php', jQuery(document));", 2000);

// on the server side create a catch.php file
<?php 
file_put_contents('./tmp.txt', 'php://input');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, easily.

JavaScript modifies the DOM in memory. This is completely separate entity than the "source" you originally sent to the browser.

The closest thing you can do is build an XML representation of the DOM via JS and send it back to the server via AJAX. Why you would want/need to do this is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Bookmarks/Favorites and create a new one with this and then click it after your page loads:

```
javascript:IHtml=document.documentElement.innerHTML;
LThan=String.fromCharCode(60);
LT=new RegExp(LThan,'g');
IHtml=IHtml.replace(LT,'&lt;');
IHtml=IHtml.replace(/  /g,'&nbsp; ');Out ='';Out+='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional\/\/EN"';Out+='  "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
Out+='<html xmlns="http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">';
Out+='<head><title>Inner HTML<\/title><\/head>';
Out+='<body style="color:black;background-color:#ffffee;">';
Out+='Body HTML:<br \/><ul>';
NLine=String.fromCharCode(10);
ILines=IHtml.split(NLine);
for (ix1=0; ix1< ILines.length; ix1++) {
    Out+='<li>'+ILines[ix1]+'<\/li>';
}
Out+='<\/ul>';
Out+='&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.close();" title="close">Close<\/a>]';
Out+='<\/body><\/html>\n';
PopUp1=window.open('','IHTML');
PopUp1.document.write(Out);
PopUp1.document.close();
```