# Is "Page Source" BEFORE or AFTER JavaScript has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

In Firefox there is a menu item that displays "Page Source": View | Page Source (Ctrl+U).
In Internet Explorer there is a similar function.

When you invoke it, it displays a nicely formatted and syntax-highlighted collection of HTML (and JavaScript) code.

What I don't know is whether this HTML (viewable in the Page Source) is the result of *pre-processing* of the JavaScript (resulting in modification of the original raw HTML) or just *raw* as received by HTTP GET.

Comment: I made the [View Rendered Source](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-rendered-source/ejgngohbdedoabanmclafpkoogegdpob) Chrome extension to show the raw and rendered source side by side, including the difference between the two

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "View Source" code is the code **before** any JavaScript is applied.

Firefox's Web Dev toolbar will allow you to view the resulting post-JavaScript source code from the View Source > View Generated Source menu option.

Comment: +1 Also, if you have Firebug installed in FF you can see javascript functions changing the page elements real time. Useful for things like animations and what not.

Comment: You don't need an add-on. You can also select any section of the page, right-click, and choose "View Selection Source".

Comment: @mrtsherman @lwburk and all the rest below. Your answers are remarkably educating. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Before. The page source is the result of the GET request by the browser sans headers. If you want to view the updated content after scripts and so forth, you'll have to use a tool like Firebug or the Web Development toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it will always display the HTML as the page was before DOM-change by javascript, etc. So the answer is: what you are seeing is "raw as received by HTTP GET".

You can use a tool like Firebug (Firefox & Chrome) to see live dom changes. Or you can make your own function to display the live dom.

Comment: Can you point me to a source (example, sample or tutorial) that shows how to write such function that displays the live DOM?

Answer (score 3):

It is the source that was returned to the browser by the server, before DOM updates made through javascript.