# Example Websites that result in substantially different HTML after Javascript processed

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

[After realizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301554/is-page-source-before-or-after-javascript-has-been-rendered) the difference between "raw HTTP GET response" and "live DOM" and how to access both, I have been trying web sites/pages that have a significant difference between the two.

By "significant difference" I mean truly *new* HTML content, not just replacement of escape codes by characters or whitespace differences.

For example, on this site ([stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301554/is-page-source-before-or-after-javascript-has-been-rendered)) the difference isn't substantial.

I am trying to learn how Javascript engines do their magic automatically on page load (before any user interaction), so examples for relatively simple such sites would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: [Gawker.com](http://www.gawker.com) and their family of sites. Pretty much everything is loaded via JS/AJAX. (It's completely unusable without JS enabled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try articles on [Gawker](http://gawker.com/). They load completely from JavaScript. In my opinion, it is also a good example of how not to do it.

Comment: +1, I do not see why to suppress the browser's capability of navigating to pages regularly.

Comment: any clue on how are they doing it? they also change adddress in the address bar.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Since I posted this answer, Gawker has changed their URLs again. It used to be something like `http://gawker.com/#!123456789/some-title`, but now they are using something more sensible. As to your qeustion: normally one would use `window.location` or `window.location.hash` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Well certainly a stand-out example would be GMail. (The "fancy" one, not the "basic HTML" one obviously.)