# View full page source after javascript has run ('view generated source') in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

We can see the source after the javascript has run *for a single element* by [right clicking on that element and clicking 'inspect element'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6868596/5783745).

Firefox lets us see the ***full page*** source by through [view source -> view generated source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301568/5783745).

How can we do this in chrome? That is, how can we see the **full** page source *after* javascript has run in chrome?

Comment: There's no such feature in Chrome. As a workaround you can right-click on `<html>` node in the elements inspector and click "Edit as HTML".

Comment: Thank you, @wOxxOm, that works great and it should be posted as an answer. You can also select <html> and hit F2, and you can also copy and paste the whole thing into an external editor to view it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done natively in Chrome, but the [View Rendered Source extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-rendered-source/ejgngohbdedoabanmclafpkoogegdpob?hl=en) does this and also compares the rendered source to the raw source. You can also access extension via right click.