# Extract video id of preceding youtube advertisement

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, ads

I'm writing a script that does stuff with the youtube advertisment videos that people have to watch before the actual videos. (These ad-vids at the start are just simple youtube videos from the brand's channel)
I've searched the whole source code and scripts, but I can't find the video id of those ads anywhere. It must be somewhere, but it seems to be hidden well.

Anybody got an idea where to look?

Comment: Can you give some more detailed information? What concrete APIs are you using, and in which code files were you looking for the id?

Comment: I'm speaking of the general source code of the youtube web page when playing a video. I'm writing a greasemonkey script that needs the video id of the advertisement video if one is played. (those advertisments are just simple youtube videos from the brands channel).
My question is whether the advertisement video id can be found somewhere in the source code of the page. It must be somewhere in the scripts that also load the main video but i cant find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on your case.

The video id of the ad video is definitively not part of the initial source code, as you already figured out. Youtube makes an ajax-Request to the http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ API to get information about related ad videos.

If you take a look into the source code, you can see a lot of javascript that is related to the google ads part. By looking into the code, you can find URL routes to the API. See screenshot, it is just an excerpt:

[image]

But unfortunately you cannot simply copy the url and make a remote-call to it. By doing so, you get a 400 Bad Request response.

As i figured out, there are missing params, which are dynamically added by youtube's javascript.

If you compare the request, that is actually made by youtube, you can see that there are more params sent:

[image]

compared to the request, that is directly copied from source code:

[image]

The result of the working request looks like this:
[image]

I tried several ways to make the invalid API request work, but have not found a way. Debugging the javascript is not that easy, because its obfuscated and minified. But additionally the variables are scoped within the function. So anyways, you would not have access to them.

If you make a javascript breakpoint right before the XHR request, you can see the actual API request:

[image]

But it is within the Local scope, without access to it.

Later on, there is even a second request to the youtube data API to fetch information about the ad video

[image]

In my opinion, there are only two ways to get the video, both require javascript to run.

1. Look into the source code AFTER Javascript has run. Then you can get the id directly from your markup:

[image]

2. Hook onto the Ajax Requests and grab the data directly from your network traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!
I'm curious how you managed to look into the source code after all Javascript has run. When I look into the source code with Firebug, I can't find any html5 video object with the data-youtube-id.
Also, if I run a javascript after all the other scripts have run, I should be able to read that video id, right?

Comment: I simply inspected the code with Chrome's Developer Tools. Here is a referred SO issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157729/how-can-you-retrieve-a-pages-source-code-after-javascript-has-ran-using-php

Comment: it seems they changed their markup logic yet again.

Comment: the advertisment video id is no longer in the markup. Could you think of any link to learn about the api request hooking you talked about?

Comment: Well actually it was just a thought experiment. So, if you look at the AJAX traffic that is triggered when the page renders, you can find the id of the ad video in one's request response. But i really have no idea, how to hook into the networks traffic and you need the javascript to be executed first.